# Catch status 500 in AngularJS from API REST

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api

I have a Angular Application that consume from API REST create in Node JS, the problem is that i'm not sure about the best form to communicate error to client, I suppose that is send message with status 500 but in this case how cath this message in Angular?

for example I have the following method in Node

```
router.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {
  models.form.create(req.body

  ).then(function(form) {
    res.send(form.dataValues)  
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log (error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  });
});
```

this is the service that use in Angular to consume

```
createForm : function (form) {
    var auxResource = $resource(localPath + 'create');
    return new auxResource(form).$save()
         .then(function (formCreated) { 
            console.log(formCreated);
            formCreate = formCreated;
         })

},
```

the controller method

```
this.create = function create () {
    formRESTService.create($scope.form)
         .then(function () {  
               $location.path("/formList");             
          })
           .catch(function (error) {
              console.log("entre al cath");
              console.log("ENTREEEEE" + error);
          });
}
```

the problem is that angular never cath the error how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple reason for that, I think.

You are using the `.then()` callback. No if you look in the documentation of `$resource` you will see, that this callback takes two functions:

`.then(function(data) {...}, function(error) {...});`

A 500 error is usually trapped in the error callback.

Afaik you can only use `.catch(...)` if you are not expecting a body in the success callback and you omit the success callback.

Please refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q where you can find a complete documentation about the promise API.